# node-phantom is not working with socket.io 1.0 and createPage() never calls callback

Tags: node.js, socket.io, phantomjs

I am using node-phantom(^0.2.5) to create pdf but its createPage function never callback and after following the link https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom/issues/102 I come to know that it is not working with socket.io 1.0. I have changed the version to 0.9.17 from 1.0.6. But in that case I am facing the issue adapter is not method of socket.io, as adapter is defined in socket.io's 1.0 version

Comment: we are also facing the same issue.